# How do I get the user's browser window size in a Delphi TMS Web Core Website?

Tags: delphi, browser, tms-web-core

I want to get the size of the browser window using Delphi, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it via the `window` class from the `WEB` unit:

```
function GetBrowserWindowSize: String;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(window.outerWidth) + 'x' + IntToStr(window.outerHeight);
end;
```